# RxJava: How can I start a task and when it has finished start another task?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a chat applicaction in Android using RxJava. The sequence of events is something like this:

- The user writes the message and push "send".
- The message object containing (id, message, sender, ...) should be stored in local database first because I need to generate his id and return the message object with the id stablished.
- Once the message object has been stored, the id has been set I have to send that message using the proper way.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to program that using RxJava, how can I start a task and when it has finished start another task? I've read about the operators zip, empty, and, when, skipuntil, flatmap, but I'm not sure which I need. I'm pretty new with RxJava.

I have this method:

```
public Observable<Boolean> sendMessage(Message message) {
    return Observable.unsafeCreate(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>()     {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
            MessageEntity messageEntity = messageToMessageEntityMapper.map(message);
            messageRepository.saveMessage(messageEntity);
            chatHelper.sendMessage(messageEntity);
            subscriber.onNext(true);
        }
    });
}
```

And the implementations of saveMessage and sendMessage:

```
public Observable<MessageEntity> saveMessage(MessageEntity messageEntity) {
    return messageCache.saveMessage(messageEntity);
}

public void sendMessage(MessageEntity messageEntity) {       
    chatConnection.sendMessage(message);
}
```

I want that sendMessage execute once saveMessage has finished and returned the expected object.

Comment: Cant you use AsyncTask? I dont know RxJava. But thats what we do in android studio

Comment: The whole application has been made using RxJava, so I try to keep the line using the same technology and architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `observable.map` to consume the result from first observable and execute the second observable.

```
public Observable<Boolean> sendMessage(Message message{ 
  MessageEntity messageEntity = messageToMessageEntityMapper.map(message); 
  return messageRepository.saveMessage(messageEntity)
          .map( updatedMessage -> {
               chatHelper.sendMessage(updatedMessage );
               return Observable.just(true);
           });
 };
```

You can also make `sendMessage` return a boolean `Observable` instead of explicitly returning `true` from the `map` method.

If there is no need to consume the emitted item from first observable, you can use `Observable.merge` instead and make `sendMessage` to return an observable.

Comment: where is **Observable.of(true)**? that function doesn't exists

Comment: Sorry Observable.of is for rxjs. Observable.just is for rxjava i guess

Comment: That way it shows this error: **no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exists so that Observable<T> conforms to Boolean inference variable R has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Boolean lower bounds: Observable<T2497540>**